# Message Collector discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

How to make a collector stop collecting same message from a user, so the example is, if someone type `catch` the bot will collect it, but if he say `catch` again the bot will no longer collect it

Here's my code

```
if (command === 'coinrain') {
    message.channel.send('Coin rain has started please type `CATCH`')
    let filter = m => m.content.toLowerCase() === 'catch';
    const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, {max: 10, time: 10000});

    collector.on('collect', m => {
        console.log(m.content);
    })

    collector.on('end', m => {
        message.channel.send({
            embed: {
                color: '#33FFF0',
                title: 'Event is over!',
                description: `${m.map(member => `${member.author.username}`).join(', ')}`
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collector?scrollTo=collected) documentation, a **MessageCollector** has a **Collected** property described as:
*The items collected by this collector*

You can use **collector.collected.includes({Object-to-check})**.
In your case you should check is a user as already sent the **catch** message. You can implement this check thanks to the properties **author** and **content** of **Message**